# Combine duplicate rows with text in columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data that looks like this:

[image: excel spreadsheet]

Column A contains multiple duplicate data. I need a formula/solution that will remove duplicate email addresses in column A, but combine data in columns B, C and D. In the end, I need it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a formula, starting in G2 enter this with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER** and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,SMALL(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH($A$2:$A$7,$A$2:$A$7,0),MATCH($A$2:$A$7,$A$2:$A$7,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$7)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROWS($G$2:G2))),"")
```

In cell H2 enter this also with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER** and copy down and across:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP("ZZZ",IF($G2=$A$2:$A$7,B$2:B$7)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like this will be the answer but having problems with it. There are 10600 rows - I tried changing the formula to have 10600 where it currently reads 7 but that didn't work. I'm just getting the first 7 rows with the same email address. I may be doing the CTL SHIFT ENTER part wrong - On a Mac if it makes a difference. Do you use that combination after pasting in the formula, instead of just hitting ENTER?

Comment: When your in edit mode, normally you just press enter to complete the formula. Instead of just pressing enter though, you are going to need to hold down CTRL+SHIFT and press ENTER.  And yes, you will need to adjust the ranges accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. if you go to the **Data** tab located in the `top navigation`,
   then go to **Data tools** (notice the headings at the bottom),
   after that click the column header that you want to remove duplicates,
   then click **Remove duplicates**.
2. To help duplicates stand out; conditional formatting in the home tab, then select quick `styles -> duplicate values`.
3. The data tab, you can use **advanced** (under Sort & Filter) formatting to only contain unique values.

Hope this helps.