# Combine and Sum Duplicate Columns in Excel

Tags: excel

My apologies in advance - this is my first question on Excel here on SE, and I am fairly new at using it (if this question should be migrated to SuperUser please let me know in comments).

I have a spreadsheet which looks like this:
[image]

I need to combine the duplicate properties, summing the rows as I go.

Thus, the outcome should look something like this:

[image]

Notice that in this example I have created a third column for the duplicate properties - this is fine, though ideally, the original columns would be hidden after the duplicate columns are summed up. I have also created another column for property 2, even though it does not have a duplicate - this is also fine, though leaving property 2 alone entirely would also be acceptable.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873638/combine-duplicate-rows-with-text-in-columns) question, but my question is somewhat different in that I am trying to sum the values, as well as attempting to sum based on duplicate columns, and not duplicate rows. I have also attempted to manipulate the instructions from [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1268-excel-combine-duplicate-rows-and-sum.html) and here, though am having little luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Insert a new column and use a SUMIF or SUMIFS then hide the other columns.

Comment: You can use a PivotTable if you transpose the data

Answer (score 1):

With this data

[image]

Add this formula starting from B6 to E6 with **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$J$1, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$6:A6, $B$1:$J$1), 0)),"")
```

And this formula starting from B7 to E8

```
=SUMIF($B$1:$G$1,B$6,$B2:$G2)
```